# How to set value to allDay tab in dayView using fullcalendar, angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, fullcalendar

[image]

Above you can see the dayview of my fullcalendar. Problem is that I cannot set a value to be shown in the all-day tab.

So, how I can set manually the value of the all-day tab using angular2?

Answer (score 0):

As described here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/ and demonstrated here:  https://fullcalendar.io/views/agendaWeek/, if you set the `allDay` property of any given event to `true`, or, alternatively, don't include times in the event's `start` and `end` dates, it will be shown in that section of the calendar. Otherwise, it'll be shown in the lower part.

e.g.

```
{
  start: "2017-01-01",
  end: "2017-01-02",
  allDay: true
}
```